# GIT/STASH for Multiple Independent Server Creation

Tags: git, git-branch, bitbucket-server

We are implementing GIT/STASH for scripts for automatic creation of application servers in AWS (Box + O/S + Application Stack) for multiple independent applications, each with their own server. Some code will be common for 2 or more servers. Prod Deployments are expected to be for 1 server at a time.

I'm thinking that we should have either 1 repo per App Server (therefore 1 for common code) , or 1 Repo for everything with maybe permanant  branches for each App Server & 1 branch for  common code. This is primarily to enable easy/automatic tracking of changes for each App Server. I'm also thinking that the Trunk should be PRODUCTION only (needing a PULL REQUEST to merge back in), so we can easily track what has changed in PRODUCTION for each AppServer

We are also using Jenkins to automatically do the build

If anyone has used GIT/STASH for something like this, I'd like to know what you recommend to handle this scenario (including branching technique)

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that stash is a separate product?  Because stash has a different meaning in a pure Git world.

Comment: It is nice you tried to emphasize some of your text, but you'd rather use **bold** text instead of CAPS (or just anything instead of caps, really).

Comment: Yes **Stash** is a separate Product ( https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash )